# How to append multiple user's input to multiple different lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the user's input to append to each list separate without it overwriting each others input. But when another user enters input it overwrites it. How do i fix this.

```
runner1stats = []
runner2stats = []
runner3stats = []

runner1  = input("What is the name of the first runner in your team?")
runner2  = input("What is the name of the second runner in your team?")
runner3  = input("What is the name of the third runner in your team?")

runners = [runner1,runner2,runner3]
for i in runners:
    race1 = int(input("Enter rider placing for race 1:"))
    race2 = int(input("Enter rider placing for race 2:"))
    race3 = int(input("Enter rider placing for race 3:"))
    race4 = int(input("Enter rider placing for race 4:"))

runner1stats.append({
        "RacerName": runner1,
        "Race1Points": race1,
        "Race2Points": race2,
        "Race3Points": race3,
        "Race4Points": race4,
    })

runner2stats.append ({
        "RacerName": runner2,
        "Race1Points": race1,
        "Race2Points": race2,
        "Race3Points": race3,
        "Race4Points": race4,
    })

runner3stats.append ({
        "RacerName": runner3,
        "Race1Points": race1,
        "Race2Points": race2,
        "Race3Points": race3,
        "Race4Points": race4,
    })
```

Comment: This is because you are overwriting then race1 race2 and race3 are overwritten at every iteration of the for loop try to append the lists at run time or store them in different lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this.

```
runner1 = input("What is the name of the first runner in your team?")
runner2 = input("What is the name of the second runner in your team?")
runner3 = input("What is the name of the third runner in your team?")

runner_stats = []  # This will end up having 3 entries by the end of the loop.
for name in [runner1, runner2, runner3]:
    race1 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 1:"))
    race2 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 2:"))
    race3 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 3:"))
    race4 = int(input(name + ": Enter rider placing for race 4:"))

    runner_stats.append({
        "RacerName": name,
        "Race1Points": race1,
        "Race2Points": race2,
        "Race3Points": race3,
        "Race4Points": race4,
    })

print(runner_stats)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in runners:
    race1 = int(input("Enter rider placing for race 1:"))
    race2 = int(input("Enter rider placing for race 2:"))
    race3 = int(input("Enter rider placing for race 3:"))
    race4 = int(input("Enter rider placing for race 4:"))
```

means "for each of the runners, set the variables race1-4 to an input value" - so each new iteration overwrites the last.

You should not be using hard-coding indices into variable names, there is a much easier and safer way:

```
runnerstats = {}
runners = []

for i, pos in enumerate(("first", "second", "third")):
    runners.append(input("What is the name of the {} runner in your team?").format(pos))

for runner in runners:
    races = []
    for i in range(4)
        races.append(int(input("Enter rider placing for race {}:".format(i+1))))
    runnerstats[runner] = races
```